# Is there a way to define global or standard function in php that can be called from anywhere without including the file

Tags: php, apache, oop

Very frequently, I need to use codes like this to see output clearly:

```
$a=print_r($var,true);
echo "<pre>$a</pre>";
```

How can convert this piece of code to a global function (for example:
`echopre`) in Php so that I can use `echopre($data)` anywhere in php
program (in my server)?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you pretty much have the answer you need in your question itself. If this is being used across multiple pages, you could put it in one PHP file and have it included in all the pages you need to call this function in.

Comment: All functions are global functions.

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger: No, I don't want to include the file inside my project files. I just want to use them as I use the other PHP functions. Like I have `print_r($Variable)`. I can use it anywhere in my code, without including any file.

Comment: So you want a custom function that's globally available, which is not native, you don't want to define it yourself, you don't want to include any files that define it and you want it to what, magically pop into existence? Are you for real?

Comment: @N.B. I clearly said that I want to code some function that I frequently use but I want them to be available everywhere in projects without including the page. And by that I mean I want to write a extension to the php. I hope this will help you to understand my question and curiosity about this and remove the vote down

Comment: Your question is absolutely horrible, no offence meant. Writing an extension is worse than having a php file auto-appended to your code which is about 500000 times easier to do. Modifying an ini file to include the .so (or compiling php with the extension) is in no way easier than using php itself to define the function and use standard mechanisms (prepend an include) to make the function globally available. Reason I downvoted you is so that next person who stumbles upon this problem has a better understanding of the problem and doesn't go down your route.

Comment: Also, writing an extension to expose functionality of a simple print_r/echo combination is really pointless. But, if it's out of curiosity and learning purposes then it does make sense, I'll admit that. But to write it for some sort of production purpose or debugging purposes - it's got absolutely 0 value.

Comment: @N.B. Its just a case I am explaining my problem. But I have many other uses for this solution. May be it could be pointless for you. But have value for my own scenarios.

Comment: @N.B. Its more more fruitful if someone have some good solution for this. But your downvote just wipe out any possibility of some good solution for someone else. I think its more constructive than just thinking its of no use.

Comment: @Navigator - include everything you had in mind then. Writing a PHP extension to implement echo + var_dump, which are native construct and native function of php is simply an overkill and there are other mechanisms to implement that. Your method for going about it is against all logic and due to that reason there's the downvote. It might seem perfectly fine to you since you didn't include all you had in mind, but from the factual standpoint - it's wrong, unless facts change. If you elaborate your use scenario where it's viable to do an extension, I'll gladly upvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If server administrator is you, you can write custom php extension and add some functions in php. For example I wrote ar_view function, which is alias of print_r with html formatting: https://github.com/akalongman/ar_view

Comment: Can you please elaborate bit more?

Comment: Look at this tutorial http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/07/07/how-to-create-php-extensions-in-c-part-i-adding-simple-function/

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you can have PHP load *functions* everywhere, per default, without inclusion.

However, you can definitely do it with classes (which, other than having to either create an object or directly access with `YourClass::echopre()` will work out the same).

Check the php config `include_path` option.

Comment: Yes, I know that it can work using the static class and without making object but needs inclusion. But I want something else. That can just be fulfill by writing custom php extension.